# Creating duplicate folder and folder structure

Tags: vba, excel

In my previous company we had a guy who created a program that would allow you to create any number of duplicate folders based on a specific folder. The beauty of the program was you could nominate how many copies you wanted to create and even nominate the names of the folders, (which was a simplistic sequential numbering system in that case). From what I recall it was a macro command in excel.  I can't contact the guy who did it and can not remember the code used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FileSystemObject for this i believe,  not sure how you'd want to set your sheet up with names for new folders & numbers etc.

but you would do something like once you have decided on the way you wish to do that.

```
Dim FSO as scripting.filesystemobject
dim FL as scripting.file
dim FLD as scripting.folder

set FSO = new scripting.filesystemobject
set FLD = fso.GetFolder("FOLDER TO COPY")

FSO.createfolder "NewFolder"

for each FL in FLd.Files
    FL.copy "NewFolder"
next FL
```